# Passing R Shiny reactive SelectInput value to selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

My Shiny app uses open data from a bird atlas, including lat/lon coordinates by species. The bird species names come in different languages, plus as an acronym.

The idea is that the user first selects the language (or acronym). Based on the selection, Shiny renders a selectizeInput list of unique bird species names. Then, when one species is selected, a leaflet map is generated.

I've done a couple of Shiny apps but this time I miss something obvious. When the app starts, all is well. But, the selectizeInput list is not re-rendered when a new language is selected.

All the present code with some sample data is here as a GitHub Gist https://gist.github.com/tts/924b764e7607db5d0a57

If somebody could point to my problem, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that both the `renderUI` and the `birds` reactive blocks are dependent on the `input$lan` input.

If you add `print(input$birds)` in the `birds` block, you will see that it uses the name of the birds before `renderUI` has a chance to update them to fit the new language. The `data` you then pass the `leaflet` plot is empty.

Try adding `isolate` around `input$lan` in the birds expressions so that it is only dependent on `input$birds`:

```
birds <- reactive({
    if( is.null(input$birds) )
      return()
    data[data[[isolate(input$lan)]] == input$birds, c("lon", "lat", "color")]
  })
```

When you change the language, the `renderUI` will change the `selectize`, which will trigger the `input$birds` and update the data.

Instead of using `renderUI`, you could also create the `selectizeInput` in your `ui.R` using (replacing the `uiOutput`):

```
selectizeInput(
        inputId = "birds", 
        label = "Select species",
        multiple  = F,
        choices = unique(data[["englanti"]])
      )
```

And in your `server.R`, update it using:

```
observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'birds', choices = unique(data[[input$lan]]))
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. Realized that I better get familiar with `isolate`and `observe` - and here I now have two use cases. Excellent.